# Pass Hint Text to Android App Using Flex Mobile Code

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, tablet

I have a Flex mobile application that is running on a 7" tablet in landscape mode.  When I call the default keyboard using the Flex code, the keyboard is hiding the entire screen and there is no way to tell what field the user is entering data in.  Without writing my own custom keyboard does anyone know if there is a way to send null text to the keyboard so the user can tell what field they are entering data for?

Comment: what do you mean by "send null text to the keyboard"?

Comment: What do you mean by "I call the default keyboard using the Flex code"

Comment: Lee - What I mean is sending a hint text.  If I set the hint text on the text box control, the hint text is shown in the text box on the screen, but when the soft keyboard comes up, there is not "hint" text that appears.  I have seen hint text on some other application on the device, but it appears that Flex Mobile is unable to send that data to the keyboard.  Unless we are missing something in the Flex mobile code that is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work using the hint of an `EditText` view. Set this up on all your `EditText`s like so:

```
<EditText
  ...
  android:hint="Phone Number"
  .... />
```

I've had this working on Samsung Galaxy Note II and Samsung Galaxy S3. When the keyboard is full-screen and the field is empty, the input field should display the hint.

Comment: Evil - Thank you for the feedback.  Is that Android code or is that Flex Mobile code?  It doesn't appear to be Flex code, in which we are using.